# How to load Specific URL page in WebView when the Push Notification is clicked

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, firebase-cloud-messaging

Iam learning Android studio and have a question about FCM notifications.

I created an android app using Webview. I also implement the FCM push notification. When I click the notification, it directly opens the homepage of my app. How can I make it open the specific page in the app when I click the notification ?

My main activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private WebView myWebView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("notifications");

    myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    myWebView.loadUrl("https://www.mywebsite.com");

    WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    myWebView.getSettings().setRenderPriority(WebSettings.RenderPriority.HIGH);
    myWebView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK);
    myWebView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
    myWebView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
    webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setLayoutAlgorithm(WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm.NARROW_COLUMNS);
    webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
    webSettings.setSavePassword(true);
    webSettings.setSaveFormData(true);
    webSettings.setEnableSmoothTransition(true);
    WebViewClient webViewClient = new WebViewClient();
    myWebView.setWebViewClient(webViewClient);
    myWebView.getSettings().setMixedContentMode(WebSettings.MIXED_CONTENT_COMPATIBILITY_MODE);

}

@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    // Check if the key event was the Back button and if there's history
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && myWebView.canGoBack()) {
        myWebView.goBack();
        return true;
    }
    // If it wasn't the Back key or there's no web page history, bubble up to the default
    // system behavior (probably exit the activity)
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

My FirebaseMessagingService :

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
/**
 * Called when message is received.
 *
 * @param remoteMessage Object representing the message received from Firebase Cloud Messaging.
 */
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(@NonNull RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);
    // TODO(developer): Handle FCM messages here.
    // If the application is in the foreground handle both data and notification messages here.
    // Also if you intend on generating your own notifications as a result of a received FCM
    // message, here is where that should be initiated. See sendNotification method below.
    RemoteMessage.Notification notification = remoteMessage.getNotification();
    Map<String, String> data = remoteMessage.getData();

    assert notification != null;
    sendNotification(notification, data);
}

/**
 * Create and show a custom notification containing the received FCM message.
 *
 * @param notification FCM notification payload received.
 * @param data FCM data payload received.
 */
private void sendNotification(RemoteMessage.Notification notification, Map<String, String> data) {
    Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher);

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    @SuppressLint("UnspecifiedImmutableFlag") PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "channel_id")
            .setContentTitle(notification.getTitle())
            .setContentText(notification.getBody())
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION))
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setContentInfo(notification.getTitle())
            .setLargeIcon(icon)
            .setColor(Color.RED)
            .setLights(Color.RED, 1000, 300)
            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);

    try {
        String picture_url = data.get("picture_url");
        if (picture_url != null && !"".equals(picture_url)) {
            URL url = new URL(picture_url);
            Bitmap bigPicture = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
            notificationBuilder.setStyle(
                    new NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle().bigPicture(bigPicture).setSummaryText(notification.getBody())
            );
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    // Notification Channel is required for Android O and above
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(
                "channel_id", "channel_name", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT
        );
        channel.setDescription("channel description");
        channel.setShowBadge(true);
        channel.canShowBadge();
        channel.enableLights(true);
        channel.setLightColor(Color.RED);
        channel.enableVibration(true);
        channel.setVibrationPattern(new long[]{100, 200, 300, 400, 500});
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
    }

    notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());
}
```

}

I am quite a newbie in Android studio. Any help is very appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In your sendNotification Method simply change the MainActivity.class to your intended activity

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, YourActivity.class);
```

Comment: Thank you Hamed, but where is MainActivity.class please?

Comment: Oh I see, you mean in my FirebaseMessagingService.java, i must change Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class); with this Intent intent = new Intent(this, YourActivity.class);  ?

Comment: Yes. Replace YourActivity with the activity name you want to open.

Comment: Im confused Hamed, where do I find the activity I want to open and replace Youractivity please

Comment: What did you mean exactly by specific page in your question? You want to open another activity or load a diffrenet page in your webview?

Comment: I mean, when I post a new article on my website, I get an FCM notification on my phone. It works perfectly. but when I click on the notification, the application opens but on its home page, and does not open the article page on my webview app.

Comment: Any help please?